# Scala ParArray pattern matching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, parallel-collections

Consider

```
val b = ParArray("a","b","c")
```

However, on pattern matching `b` for instance as follows,

```
b match {
  case ParArray(_,"b",_) => 2
  case _ => -1
}


<console>:11: error: object ParArray is not a case class, 
                     nor does it have an unapply/unapplySeq member
              case ParArray(_,"b",_) => 2
```

Thus how to pattern match `ParArray` ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can not pattern-match like that, because there is no `unapply` defined on ParArray. A workaround could be to use `b.toList match { case List(_, "b", _) => ...}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ParArray` is a parallel structure. Its main usecase is to operate on the elements concurrently (see [docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/concrete-parallel-collections.html#parallel_array)). That's done (roughly speaking) by concurrently applying operations on arbitratry segments of the ParArray.

For the sake of a counter example, imagine that you could unapply on ParArray. How would the match look like:

`Given val b = ParArray("a","b","c","d")`

```
b match {
  case ParArray(_,"b",_) => 2
  case _ => -1
}

Could be arbitrarily converted into:
//Parallel split & join:
"a","b" match {
  case ParArray(_,"b",_) => 2
  case _ => -1
}

"c","d" match {
  case ParArray(_,"b",_) => 2
  case _ => -1
}
```

Which of course, doesn't make sense. 
For the specific case on your question, you could use direct addressing:

`if (b.size == 3 && b(1)=="b") 2 else -1`

In a more generic sense, a good way of reasoning is thinking of how your operation could be applied to all elements at the same time.

If you need to `match` on structure, you could obtain an array with the `parArray.toArray` method. You should also question why is a `ParArray` being used.